# Vue 2 / Nuxt 2 Emit From Axios With Dialog Confirm

Tags: vue.js, async-await, nuxt.js

i am using Vue 2 / nuxt to emit from a axios post* call which itself is called from a Buefy dialog confirm. The emit from this component will close the window / panel and then re-load the users.

If I call the axios request from the button, this works without any issues, but once being called from the dialog, it just don't work?

*most likely this will be updated to a delete request, just not gotten to that let

See code below:

```js
removeUser() {
  this.$buefy.dialog.confirm({
    message: 'Continue on this task?',
    onConfirm: () => {
      this.removeUserFunc()
    }
  })
},

removeUserFunc() {
  // console.log(that)
  const that = this

  // Build URL
  const EndPoint = '/remove_user/' + this.id

  this.$axios.post(EndPoint).then((res) => {
    // User Remove Message
    UserRemoved(this.$swal)

    that.$parent.$emit('completed')
    // console.log(this.$emit('complete'))

    // // Emit 'completed' Message
    console.log(that.$emit('completed'))
    console.log(that)
  }).catch((res) => {
    console.log(res)
    // Check For Errors
    GeneralError(this.$swal)
  })
}
```

I was thinking it was losing access to the correct `this`, so i was trying to pass that back in, but not sure that is the case?

I have also tried with await, while that sort of works? I think is firing the emit too fast, as it re-loads the users but it still includes the user that as just been deleted?

```js
removeUser() {
  this.$buefy.dialog.confirm({
    message: 'Continue on this task?',
    onConfirm: async() => {
      this.removeUserFunc()
      await this.$emit('completed')
    }
  })
},
```

Comment: If you `console.log` inside of `removeUserFunc`, do you see it while using the modal?

Comment: You could maybe also use this one? https://buefy.org/documentation/dialog#promise (depending on `result`)

Comment: I am looking into the promise for the dialog, i must have completely missed that in the docs, thanks

Comment: So i know i am missing something, not use promises much. but I have added my ```onConfirm``` remove user function, it fires but the two consts are undefined, not sure what i am doing wrong, their example is not every detailed

Answer (score 0):

The `this` keyword refers to the object the function belongs to, or the window object if the function belongs to no object.

Try to use `.bind` and use a ES5 function

```js
removeUser() {
  this.$buefy.dialog.confirm({
    message: 'Continue on this task?',
    onConfirm: function() {
      this.removeUserFunc()
    }.bind(this)
  })
},
```

Comment: I have just tried this and the same thing - the emit does not fire the function to reload the users. It does remove the user, so it runs the post request, just not the emit